# nextjs pass current route to the higher order cmponent as parametre

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am having a hoc withAuth.js
in which i am passing a component and second parameter is current route which would render if the condtion fails

```
const Detail = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
        <div> this is the my account inside  ..... </div>
        </>
    )
};

export async function getServerSideProps({req ,res}) {
    // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
    // You can use any data fetching library
   
    // console.log('request object ', req.headers);
    
    // retun the props.api bcoz client side has no access to the baseurl from the server 
    return {
        props:{}
    }
  }

export default withAuth(Detail, loginRedirectPath);
```

my question is that how to pass the current route the hoc

**edit**
hi i have solve this problem by managing route history

Comment: By "current route", do you mean the whole URL like https://example.com/sth ?

Comment: @Hangindev yes url or path

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to actually pass this as a parameter, but you can if you so wish. As per the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), you can use the useRouter() hook (or another method such as importing the Router object) to get the current pathname. I believe this will work on either the component or HOC when using the hook, although I may be wrong on this. Regardless, using next/router to get the pathname is the approach here!